# Можно ли так оформлять связи? Если нет, то как правильно?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE Learning
(
    [number of students gradebook] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL Foreign key REFERENCES Students([number of gradebook]), 
    ID_Discipline INT NOT NULL Foreign key REFERENCES Disciplines(ID),
    [Exam date] Date NOT NULL,
    Mark int NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: да, https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Синтаксически можно. Идеологически нет - ибо не рекомендуется всё валить в одну кучу.

Comment: если задать имя констрейнта , то вполне себе нормально

Comment: я бы на вашем месте не о связях, а об именах полей задумался сначала